# Scala: filtering an array with filter vs. for each

Tags: arrays, scala, filter

I have this problem: I want to iterate on the elements of an array that satisfy a certain condition.

The first thing I though is to use the *filter* method on the original array and then iterates over the resulting elements. But I had some memory usage problem with that, i.e. java heap space.
When a *filter* is applied on an array, it will instantiate a new array? So it will copy each element?

Is it better to use this approach:

```
array.filter(<condition>).foreach{ element =>
   do something
}
```

Or the following one?

```
for(i <- array.indices if <condition>){
   do something
}
```

Moreover, I wrote these two tests:

With *for*

```
val size = 10000000
val elements = Array.ofDim[Double](size)
for (i <- elements.indices) {
  elements.update(i, math.random)
}
var cont = 0
val n = 0.5
while(true){
  cont = 0
  for (j <- elements.indices if elements(j) < n) {
    cont += 1
  }
  println(cont)
}
```

with *filter*

```
val size = 10000000
val elements = Array.ofDim[Double](size)
for (i <- elements.indices) {
  elements.update(i, math.random)
}

val n = 0.5
while(true){
  val valid = elements.filter(x => x < n)
  println(valid.size)
}
```

and I checked the memory usage with VisualVM, it seem that the first solution uses less memory than the second one.

This is the memory used by the first solution
[image]

This is the memory used by the second solution
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `for` expression use the `withFilter` method rather than `filter`, which avoids creating the intermediate `Array`. So either use the `for` version or use `withFilter` rather than `filter`.